# Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'apply_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'Job'

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE DATABASE  Wuzzuf;

USE Wuzzuf;

CREATE TABLE  Company_Data (
    Name    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    City            VARCHAR(15),
    Country         VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Company_URL     VARCHAR(30),
    Foundation_Date  DATE,
    Size            INT,
    URL             VARCHAR(50) 
);

CREATE TABLE User (
    Email_Address   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FName           VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Lname           VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    City            VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    Country         VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    Phone           CHAR(11)    NOT NULL,   
    Birthdate       DATE         NOT NULL,
    Gender          CHAR         NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Job (
    Company_Name    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Position            VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    City            VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    Country         VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    Salary          INT NOT NULL,
    Career_level    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Experience      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Education_level     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Vacancies       INT         NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Company_Name) REFERENCES Company_Data(Name)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (Company_Name, Position)
);

CREATE TABLE Job_Type (
    Company_Name    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Job_title       VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Job_Type            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Company_Name) REFERENCES Company_Data(Name)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (Job_title) REFERENCES Job(Position)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (Company_Name, Job_title, Job_Type)
);

CREATE TABLE Apply (
    Job_title       VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    User_Email      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    Cover_letter    VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY (User_Email) REFERENCES User(Email_Address)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (Job_title) REFERENCES Job(Position)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (Job_title, User_Email)
);
```

I'm trying to create this database on MySQL but I keep getting the same error:

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'apply_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'Job'

whenever I try to add Job_title as a foreign key to (Job_Type, Job_Category, Job_skills, Apply) even though job title is a primary key. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Please un-tag sql-server if that is not the database your question refers to. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423302/why-does-tagging-multiple-rdbms-products-make-my-question-unclear

Comment: You have a composite primary key on Job therefore you need a composite foreign key to reference it. However I would suggest not using composite keys at all. Rather use agnostic auto-inc keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can only create foreign key constraints which target columns which are uniquely constrained. `Job.Position` is not uniquely constrained. Yes, it is *part* of a unique constraint, but by itself, it is not unique. If you wanted to foreign key to `Job` you would have to have your foreign key include both primary key columns; i.e. `Company_Name` and `Job_title`. If you want to constrain *just* `Position`, you're going to need a separate `Position` (or `job_title`, depending on which nomenclature you go with) table.

For what it's worth, that's one of the reasons for having auto-incrementing surrogate keys for tables. If you want to reference `Job`, you just reference it by the single integer key value, rather than having to duplicate the entire composite key in any table which references it.